# How to know facebook access token expiry time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am implementing spring-social-facebook 2.0.3.RELEASE, however I would like to know how to retrieve the access token expiry time?

Below is the code to access facebook to fetch user profile, but how to retrieve the access token expiry time?

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);
String[] fields = { "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name" };
User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```

Comment: `expiry` is included in the data returned from the endpoint where you get the token from (for the server-side login flow at least.) If you need to find out the expiry for an already existing token, you can debug it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling

Comment: What is the different between input-token vs access-token? Which value should I put?

Comment: The documentation explains that, doesn’t it?